# Is there a way to disable the "next" button for an editText that is set to numbers?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

My current layout consists of a parent `FrameLayout` wrapping a single `EditText`. I'm only using this layout to try and figure out a way to disable the "next" button(see highlighted button below) because if that button was pressed it flips to a text keyboard and the `EditText` is no longer focused. **This is running from Pixel emulated device**.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can include `android:imeOptions="actionNone"` on your `<EditText>` element in the manifest to say that you do not need an action button. There are other possibilities for [`android:imeOptions`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/widget/TextView#android:imeoptions) that might suit your needs better.

Bear in mind that there are hundreds of input method editors (soft keyboards) available for Android. Requests like `android:imeOptions="actionNone"` are hints, not demands. Whether the user's keyboard pays attention to `actionNone` is up to the developers of the keyboard.

Comment: Yeah. Seems like this is not possible.

Comment: I'll mark this as the answer cause it does do answer my question. Even if the issue is device specific.